Creating Salesforce ContentVersion using Power Automate Salesforce Connector "Create Record" but pdf isn't valid
I'm trying to create a ContentVersion record with a pdf file using the file content from "Get File Content Using Path" action. It looks like it's retrieved by the "Get File Content Using Path" as a base64 string in the Power Automate flow.  Here is what I'm using in the Create Record action:

I use this expression for the Version Data parameter: @{body('Get_file_content_using_path')}
When I try to create the ContentVersion record it seems to succeed, but the pdf file in Salesforce says it's not valid.  Salesforce documentation says that it expects base64, and that is supposedly what is being sent, so I'm lost about what's happening. I try sending the pdf file to myself in the flow as an email attachment, and I can view the pdf attachment in Outlook just fine, so there is something happening between Power Automate and Salesforce.
Try to create ContentVersion with pdf attachment, and I was expecting to be able to view it in Salesforce.
